# create function to edit multiple columns in pandas dataframe - columns differ by 1 digit

Tags: python, pandas

I have 11 columns

```
df.columns = ["Document","Subject1","Subject2","Subject3","Subject4","Subject5","Subject6","Subject7","Subject8","Subject9","Subject10"]
```

I want to create a function that goes over each of these columns and performs a few operations to clean up / split the data.

This is what I have.

```
columns = df['Subject{0}']
def split_data():    
    for col in columns:
       df['Subject_{0}_URI'] = col.str.split('>', 1).str[0] + '>'
       df['Subject{0}'] = col.str[:-6] 
       df['Subject_{0}'] = col.str.split('>', 1).str[1]
       df1 = df.drop(col, axis = 1)
       df1.to_excel('/merged_results.xlsx', index = False)

split_data()
```

This is the error I am getting

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/merge_results.py", line 44, in <module>
    split_data()
  File "/merge_results.py", line 39, in split_data
    df3['Subject_{0}_URI'] = df3['Subject{0}'].str.split('>', 1).str[0] + '>'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3807, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Subject{0}'
```

Comment: You're trying to access a column called **exactly** `Subject{0}`. Did you mean something like `"Subject{0}".format(3)` (where `3` would be the suffix for the different column names) ? See [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/#the-name-component)

Comment: You can do `names = [col for for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Subject')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You've faced a `KeyError`. It says the `'Subject{0}'` does not exist in your columns. It's true, your columns are `["Document","Subject1","Subject2","Subject3","Subject4","Subject5","Subject6","Subject7","Subject8","Subject9","Subject10"]` and none is `'Subject{0}'`.
If you only need to do the stuff with `"Subject"` columns, and not `"Document"`, do this:

```
def split_data(): 
    for i in range(1, 11):   # NOTE
        df[f'Subject_{i}_URI'] = df[f'Subject{i}'].str.split('>', 1).str[0] + '>'
        df[f'Subject{i}'] = df[f'Subject{i}'].str[:-6] 
        df[f'Subject_{i}'] = df[f'Subject{i}'].str.split('>', 1).str[1]
        df1 = df.drop(['Subject{i}'], axis = 1)
        df1.to_excel('/merged_results.xlsx', index = False)
```

In this case, `f'Subject{i}'` formats your column names in such a way that at each iteration, one numeric value of will be replaced instead of i, for instance, `'Subject{5}'`. This modification solves your issue and If you *only* have `'Subject1'` to `'Subject10'` columns, it works finely. In case there are varying number of columns, you have to change other things too, so, please let me know and I will help you.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! This worked great. I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that! Any other questions and I'm here for you!